# How to migrate Parse files to mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-server

I'm migrating a Parse application from Parse.com to Heroku. I've followed the [Migration Guide](https://parse.com/migration) and was able to deploy the app on Heroku with mLab MongoDB, transfer the database, and also host the Dashboard on Heroku as well. The last step is to migrate the files hosted on Parse.com to Heroku. I was able to use the [files utility](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils) to download the files to my computer using the parse-server-fs-adapter, but it looks like it's not possible to migrate the files to the MongoDB hosted on Heroku. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello @Wolfy, did you find anything on it?

Comment: @SudipPodder unfortunately not. It looks like it's not possible to migrate files to Heroku (or other hosted Parse servers).

Comment: So what's your alternative approach? @Wolfy

Comment: @SudipPodder I have none to suggest, unfortunately. Being able to migrate the old files was a nice to have, but not strictly required for our project. So we just downloaded the old files and kept them in a repository offline.